# In-line assembly error

Tags: solidity, assembly

I am checking if an address is a smart contract. Similarly to many articles and example-codes out there, i do this within my function:

```
uint32 size;
assembly{
    size := extcodesize(_to)
}
if(size > 0){}
```

However, when I do this, as so many others seem to do, I get this error:

> security/no-inline-assembly: Avoid using Inline Assembly.

I seem to struggle to find a solution to this. Even in the solidity 0.5.0 documentation they describe inline assembly, so seems weird that it is not allowed. Has anyone else encountered this, and found a solution to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Remix, this should only give you the following warning, not an error. It gives you an idea as to *why* you should avoid assembly (presumably unless you know what you're doing).

> The Contract uses inline assembly, this is only advised in rare
>   cases. Additionally static analysis modules do not parse inline
>   Assembly, this can lead to wrong analysis results.

If you're using `solc` directly, then I think you'll need to play around with the `solhint` configuration, specifically under the [Security Rules](https://github.com/protofire/solhint/blob/master/docs/rules.md#security-rules) section. (See the `no-inline-assembly` rule.) You should be able to set it to 'false'. (Though on your head be it.)

For your specific piece of code, you need to be careful - it might not do what you expect it to do. See the Consensys Best Practices for why:

- [Avoid using extcodesize to check for Externally Owned Accounts](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/#avoid-using-extcodesize-to-check-for-externally-owned-accounts)